# pytesseract.TesseractError: (-5, 'dyld: Library not loaded: Reason: image not found)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tesseract, python-tesseract

When using the image_to_string() function in Pytesseract, I am getting the following error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 164, in image_to_string
raise TesseractError(status, errors)
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (-5, 'dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblept.4.dylib\n  
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tesseract\n  Reason: image not found')
```

Tried reinstalling Tesseract (view Brew), PyTesseract, PIL, with no luck.
Had no problems on the other machines I tested on, all are OSX Yosemite 10.10.3.

Stumped.

Comment: What happens if you `brew update && brew upgrade`, then `brew install tesseract`?

Comment: well ill be darned, that resolved the issue. thanks tristan.

Comment: I'll post an answer for future askers.  Please accept or add details if you had to do something else to resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

`dyld` is a [dynamic linker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) modifier -- it more or less helps find libraries.  You should be able to get it to find the liblept (leptonia) by a reinstall:
`brew update && brew upgrade && brew install tesseract`

Alternatively, you could to find the library it's searching for and either copy it into its path or create a link.